# Current draw Raspberry Pi 4 measurement results. Does anyone have more data?

Tags: power-supply, hat, current

I thought this would help with designing HAT power. Does anyone have similar measurements while running software and connected devices?
Scant information on the current draw. I measured through the 30s start up and then pulsed a 100 mA 3.3V load on the I/O pins. You can see the initial spike of 1.3A which is just charging up the on board filter capacitors and starting the power converters. After about 30s, the current drops to a steady state value of about 300 mA. You can see the effect of my pulsed 100 mA load between 50s and 70s. No other devices were connected and there was no programming running while making this measurement.

The 3.3V output has 0.15% load regulation at 100 mA.
[image: 5V input current during start up plus 100 mA pulsed 3.3V load]

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes there is: in title and first lines of the message you can see. It is repeated here to help you: Does anyone have similar measurements while running software and connected devices?

Comment: Not to be rude, but have you read the documentation; [What types of question should I avoid asking?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)? IOW, yeah, I see it's a question, but so is "What color is the sky in your world?"... it's njust ot a good question for SE. Your Q might be better suited to the raspberry pi forums??

Comment: Is this not a Raspberry Pi related forum? The title seems to indicate that it is.  "What color is the sky in your world?" Since you declare rude =0 then now silly=1?  By your standards it is not a good question , but it is according to the link you sent. Maybe you should read it.  You probably don't deal with hardware much, if you did you would want to know current. Its missing from all the Raspberry Pi documentation I can find. Feel free to add you constructive feedback to my thread including any current draw information you might have. The last word on this is all yours Seamus. Cheers

Comment: Do you want measurements from a smart outlet strip plug which has an adapter to 5v and USB type c to plug into a Pi 4?

Comment: cybernard,  It would be great to have that information. Also please measure with your application running and share what other devices you have connected.
Thanks